# How to perform Key Listener on SWT Label

Tags: java, swt

KeyListener is not performed on Label. Please help any one?
Below is Code snippet:

```
breakNodeLabel = new Label(this, SWT.WRAP);
breakNodeLabel.setBackground(new Color(getDisplay(), 204, 204, 204));
breakNodeLabel.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.keyCode == SWT.DEL) {
        // deleteNode(this);
        System.out.println("------------Delete Break NODE----------------");
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added KeyListener to Label. 
Label must have focus to get events.

If you want to listen for keyboard events in your whole window then add KeyListener to your shell:

```
shell.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()...
```

If you want global KeyListener add display filter:

```
Listener listener = new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e) {
        if(e.type == SWT.KeyDown||e.type == SWT.KeyUp) {
            System.out.println("" + e.keyCode);
        }
    }
};
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
display.addFilter(SWT.KeyUp, listener);
```

Comment: breakNodeLabel.getShell().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {.............. also not working.Please give any other idea.

Comment: I have a Label on which image is reside , So can't use text. May you have idea i use button change its look and feel like Label.(Removing border of Button)

Comment: Use display.addFilter

Comment: working for display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener); but display.addFilter(SWT.DEL, listener) is not.

Comment: SWT.DEL is not an event type, add KeyDown listener then in handleEvent method test if e.keyCode == SWT.DEL

Comment: Now KeyLisner is working but when click on other component every time same composite is called  --                                                                  org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Widget is disposed
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4441)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4356)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4327)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:476)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:348)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.getParent(Control.java:1500)

Answer (score 2):

`Label` does not support key events.

You could use a read only `Text` control instead:

```
new Text(this, SWT.READ_ONLY | SWT.WRAP);
```